# Windows Scheduled Task refuse to run

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to setup a daily task ([running CTest from a batch script](https://openjpeg.googlecode.com/svn/dev-utils/ctest_scripts/hpdesk_openjpeg.bat)). I have used the default GUI of my Vista Pro 32bits, and setup the following task:

```
> schtasks /query /tn "trunk nightly" /xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2014-04-17T11:44:43.2643714</Date>
    <Author>PC-de-optiplex3\voxxl</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2014-04-17T05:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
      <UserId>PC-de-optiplex3\voxxl</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Dashboards\ctest_scripts\hpdesk_openjpeg.bat</Command>
      <WorkingDirectory>C:\Dashboards\ctest_scripts\</WorkingDirectory>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

From the GUI, it tells me that the last run happened on the **24th**, while today is the **28th**, so clearly it runs *properly* for a couple of days and then stop. Is there a way to setup a daily windows tasks, that actually runs on **daily** basis ?
My user has admin rights, has a password, and workstation is properly plugged (no power outage during the week end).

As can be seen from the *XML* output, the flag `WakeToRun` is properly set to `true`. From the power management system, I cannot however set the famous `Allow wake timers` (interface if in french but clearly the 4th parameters is missing, simply compare with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501109/allow-wake-timers-windows-7-vista))

[image]

here is the same screenshot after I click on `Change settings that are currently unavailable`:

[image]

Clearly the code above **does not make use of any UI** at all at least it does not open anything when I right click 'execute' from the windows schedulers panel. It run smoothly when executed by hand.

It looks just as if a task cannot run when computer is asleep...

Comment: is it working when executed manualy (right click / start) ? can you test another time and see if it is OK when the computer is awake ?

Comment: Following on from @Kayasax's q, does the script have some UI interaction that won't work when the workstation is asleep ?

Comment: no UI interaction at all

Comment: Set a start time for like 5 minutes from now then check your event logs. Could be a permissions issue for some reason or something else equally fun. Another thing I'd do to help troubleshoot: in the command that points to the script in schedtask add the line ">hpdesk_openjpeg_output.txt" to the end of that command. This would  save the output to a text file as if you ran it straight from cmd - but using the scheduled task process which can sometimes cause fun behaviors you wouldn't catch otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable wake up timers in the power savings plan options:
`Control Panel` -> `Power Options` -> `Change plan settings` -> `Change advanced power settings`.
In the list, item `Sleep`, change `Allow wake timers` to `Enable`.

The GUI parameters for the scheduled task should include :

In the **General** tab:

- Check `Run whether user is logged in or not`

In the **Conditions** tab:

- Check `Wake the computer to run this task`.

If there is no `Wake the computer to run this task` checkbox, then most probably
your BIOS or hardware do not support wake timers, which is why Windows will not display the option.

If that's the case, the only other idea I have is, if wake-on-LAN is supported, to maybe do the waking from another computer on the network.

Comment: Here is the documentation for Vista: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929463 I do not see anything like what you described from my vista environment.

Comment: It would be easier to fire up the Task Scheduler and check.

Comment: let me rephrase my intial comment into: after searching in my vista installation I do not see anything called "Allow wake timers". Furthermore I took an extra (afterward) step to check online if I could find it, and I found the above link to microsoft documention.

Comment: I don't have Vista, but [this link](http://www.ehow.com/how_8537459_make-vista-not-resume-hibernation.html) shows how to reach "Allow wake timers" on Vista, and it's effectively different from Windows 7. If this works for you, I'll add it in my answer.

Comment: I've added a screenshot (sorry it's in French) of what parameters I can change. 'Allow wake timers' is not among them.

Comment: Pas de problème. You might be able make the change in the registry. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12595731/165358) (requires reboot). Is there anything in the BIOS about wake? Is Vista fully patched?

Comment: I am starting to think that your BIOS or hardware do not support wake timers, which is why Windows will not display the option. If that's the case, the only other idea I have is, if wake-on-LAN is supported, to maybe do the waking via another computer on the network.

Comment: I am doing a `wakeonlan ...` from a linux machine and everything went well over the week end. thanks much for the trick !

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to get the task scheduler to work for you, and, your task is started from **sleep** or **hibernation**, have a look at [WakeOnStandby](http://www.dennisbabkin.com/wosb/).  It's free and it just might provide what you're looking for.